# What are the applications of sha3 algorithm?

Tags: hash, sha-3

I know it is used for digitally signing any data or message. It can be used for sending any message securely, but where is it applied in industries? Can anyone tell the practical applications of $\text{SHA-3}$ in brief?

Comment: SHA-3 is a family of hash algorithms, enacted in August 2015, which is recent. Therefore there are few actual uses, if any. Are you asking how members of the SHA-3 family _could_ be used ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far too broad and probably a duplicate. Hence I'll provide you a quick (& dirty) and completely incomplete answer but it will give you a general idea.

$\text{SHA-3}$ is a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). It is the [NIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology) name for the [Keccak](http://keccak.noekeon.org/) algorithm. Hence its usage is the same as the one of hash functions.

It is also possible to use it as XOF (eXtended Output Function) : $\text{SHAKE256}$, therefore as a stream cipher.

---

> I know its used for digitally signing any data or message.

Wrong. You do not sign anything with a hash function. For this you need a [signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). It implies non-repudiation which cannot be provided with hash functions. However hash functions can be used to verify integrity via a [$\text{MAC}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

Comment: Then again, you could use a simplified scheme for a MAC instead of HMAC when using SHA-3 because it is not vulnerable against lenght extension attacks.

Comment: I know its for digitally signing but which all companies are using it and where???